# Activate charge id for app returns 404 Shopify?

Tags: php, shopify, billing, shopify-app

I am implementing a billing in my app by following https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/charging-for-your-app/guides/implement-billing-model#implement-the-applicationcharge-resource

With this I have been able to generate the charge id, but during activate of charge id I go the 404 not found.

The charge endpoint is something like this https://store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-04/application_charges/9878536240/activate.json

And body is as below

```
{
  "application_charge": {
    "id": 9878536240,
    "name": "iPod Cleaning",
    "api_client_id": 755357713,
    "price": "5.00",
    "status": "accepted",
    "return_url": "http:\/\/google.com",
    "created_at": "2017-07-19T12:24:00-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-19T12:24:00-04:00",
    "test": null,
    "charge_type": null,
    "decorated_return_url": "http:\/\/google.com?charge_id=675931192"
  }
}
```

Every time I got a 404 not found in response. What am I missing or doing wrong?